# DreamWeaver Error: While executing DW_BCC canAcceptCommand in BCC.htm, a JavaScript error occured

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

Anyone else ever received this error?  Google has 2 unhelpful references to it and no real information.  Adobe has a link to debugging JS errors but it's 404...

Error is "While executing DW_BCC canAcceptCommand in BCC.htm, a JavaScript error occurred"

BCC.htm is not a file in any of my sites.  I assume it is some sort of action template (with a concerning name) that DreamWeaver employs.

Answer (score 0):

Errors like that usually start happening due to corruption in the Dreamweaver cache file.  The easiest thing to do to fix it is:

1) Close Dreamweaver

2) Locate the Cache file.  On a Windows 7 machine it will be at:

```
C:\Users\YOU\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS(X)\en_US\Configuration
```

Where `YOU` is your Windows user name and `X` is the version of Creative Suite being used.

3) In that folder there is a file named `WinFileCache-XXXXXXX.dat`.  Delete that file and restart Dreamweaver.

If for some reason that doesn't fix the problem, there are other steps that can be taken.

Alternate 1: After closing Dreamweaver, open the Extension Manager and disable all extensions for Dreamweaver.  Then follow the steps above.

Alternate 2: Close Dreamweaver and then delete the configuration folder.  Dreamweaver will rebuild it using default settings the next time you open the program.